# Where to get a SAML certificate

Tags: saml

I am new to this concept of SAML certificates.

I am currently working on configuring an SSO for a website and need to know how I can generate a SAML certificate? The setup I am using for this website is not via Azure, but directly from the vendor site and they are requesting my SAML certificate. Do I need a special tool to do this? and does it need to be registered before sending it out?

Answer (score 11):

Run the command below to create the certificate
e.g:

```
keytool -genkey -alias saml -dname "CN=mydomain.com, C=NO" -keystore saml-keystore -keyalg RSA -validity 730 -keysize 1024
```

Send the public certificate to the SAML Consumer party

The SAML Consumer needs to know the public part of your certificate. You may export the public part of the certificate and send this.

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore saml-keystore -alias saml -file saml-cert.public
```

[Here](https://support.signicat.com/display/S2/How+to+create+a+SAML+certificate+for+use+with+the+SAML+Library) is whole details also it, Also there is some other online tool which helps in create certificate online like [samltool](https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php)

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as SAML certificate. SAML uses self-signed X.509 certificates that can be generated manually using the `openssl`. There are number of tutorials [on the web](https://www.google.pl/search?q=generate%20self%20signed%20certificate%20openssl) how to create such certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Some identity provider will generate the public key and certificate for you.

Keycloak does this and will allow to copy it in the Realms settings.

[image: Keycloak Realms Keys]